# Webpack built typescript files-modules are empty objects

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript2.0

I have this in webpack config

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' }
  ]
}
```

also this in tsconfig.json

```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "files": [
      "./src/library.ts",
      "./src/test-utils.ts",
      "./src/request-service",
      "./typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
  }
```

and this in tests for mocha:

```
const Library = require('../dist/library');

const testUtils = require('../dist/test-utils');

const MockRequestService = testUtils.MockRequestService;

const assert = require('assert');

const djs = new Library('/');
```

testUtils and Library are empty objects. So new Library throws error that it cannot be used with new because it's not a constructor.

I did dir proper export default and exports as I did in simple babel+es6 build and files in /dist seem to be ok. Trying to figure out, maybe I did something wrong with typescript config (new to it)?

edit: worth saying, I have something like dependency to webpack entry point (test-utils import interfaces from library) but (!) because of interfaces in TypeScript, I import only them from another modules, this is why there is hack in webpack config ([] brackets for entries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> testUtils and Library are empty objects. So new Library throws error that it cannot be used with new because it's not a constructor.

Use `import` instead of require:

```
import Library = require('../path/to/src/library');
```

And run mocha with ts-node : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#mocha

Comment: Thanks! Some additional info for those seeking help with this:

Comment: You cannot use webpack bundled modules in nodejs tests as they were like node modules (without specifically building them for node). So... Better test the source, then!